# Why can't I import a package installed with easy_install?

Tags: python

I tried to install the `SimpleCV` package:

```
C:\>easy_install C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\simplecv-1.2-py2.7.egg
Processing simplecv-1.2-py2.7.egg
simplecv 1.2 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed c:\python27\lib\site-packages\simplecv-1.2-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for simplecv==1.2
Finished processing dependencies for simplecv==1.2
```

But when I try to import it, it doesn't work:

```
import simplecv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named simplecv
>>> from SimpleCV import Shell
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\SimpleCV\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    # $Id$
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\SimpleCV\base.py", line 29, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cv
```

Why can't I import it?

Comment: it is strange you use  `import simplecv` but also `from SimpleCV import`. Python is case sensitive...

Comment: Do you have openCV installed? http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide

Answer (score 2):

You should install [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide). And OpenCV may require some other libraries to be installed, namely [PyGame](http://pygame.org/install.html)

I don't know if there are some automated procedures for Windows, in my Ubuntu I just issued two commands (in addition to easy_install of simplecv):

```
sudo apt-get install python-pygame
sudo apt-get install python-opencv
```

After that it worked both ways:

```
>>> import SimpleCV
>>> from SimpleCV import Shell
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you just try:

```
import SimpleCV
```

or

```
from SimpleCV import *
```

python is case-sensitive.